# Best way to handle a mailing list/RSS feed subscribers?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint portal which displays daily news in a visual webpart. This webpart is linked to a list. I would like to provide users the possibility to suscribe to this list (mail or RSS) so that they can receive the content of the news without having to go on the website. I have never used this SP functionnality, therefore I would like to have your opinion about the best way to handle it ?

I have thought of creating a "subscribers" list. A button "suscribe" on the aspx would add the current user to this list, which would be taken as a source for the RSS feed/mailing list.

Another possibity would be to redirect the user to the RSS suscribing page of sharepoint "view RSS feeds", or the mailing list "Alert me", but maybe would it be less ergonomic... I don't know.

Don't hesitate to give me your point of view, thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some special requirements you didn't mention, there's no need to create a custom solution - just add two links to your Web Part:

1. link to an RSS feed of the list,
2. link to a page allowing to create alerts for the list.